# Do programs add keys to root authorized keys file

Tags: ssh, security, keys

During the setup of a vps I created ssh keys and use those to access the vps. I installed the following software on the vps:

Tripwire
Fail2ban
Tiger
mmap
mod_security
rkhunter
MailUtils/postfix
Logwatch
Apparmor

A few days ago I discovered 2 sections (one with 1 key plus 4x another key (same key)) The keys are from: fu-infra-distrib@cache-ng

The sections mentioned contain the text: # The following ssh key was injected by Nova

I don't know whether I should remove these keys as I don't know where they are from. They are associated with the root user authorized keys.

My guess would be that one of the softwares mentioned uses the keys to perform its tasks/scans etc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, These programs doesn't add public key to authorized_keys ,, I think it may be added by any of server admin.. you should take backup of that file,, identify your connection key pair, and then try removing other keys carefully..

Comment: Thanks, thats what I just did. I backed up the extra keys then removed them.; Il use/scan with the programs I installed and see if there is anything not functioning. One of the keys is ovh.com (my supplier) but the key is only on one server and I have 3 which is also strange. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

the message "The following ssh key was injected by Nova" comes from Openstack Nova project, which probably means that OVH uses Openstack to provision their VPS, at least in some datacenter(s).
See: https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/master/nova/virt/xenapi/agent.py
and: https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/
It comes from there, I believe.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks Patrox, i removed it but I will take a l9ok at your suggestions. Cheers